# Users without roles are crashing my site. Whats the best way to use conditional chaining to help the site deal with user roles being null?

Tags: reactjs

So hopefully that question made sense.
Right now I am in a coding bootcamp and they have assigned me to fix the bug that is causing our product site to crash. When a user is created they are not assigned a role type. The roles that we have are:
customer
Blogger
orgmember
orgAdmin
Sysadmin

So when we render the default navbar at the top, certain links become available for certain users that are allowed access to them. However, when just a base user is created, they are not assigned a role. So when it goes to check the role type, it encounters currentUsers.roles : null and breaks the code.
I just wanted to see if there was a better way of handling this.

```
const mapNavLink = (item, index) => {
if (
  currentUser.isLoggedIn === true &&
  item?.roles?.includes(currentUser.roles[0])
) {
  if (item.children === undefined) {
    return (
      <Nav.Link key={index} as={Link} to={item.link}>
        {item.menuitem}
      </Nav.Link>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <NavDropdownMain
        item={item}
        key={index}
        onClick={(value) => setExpandedMenu(value)}
      />
    );
  }
} else if (currentUser.isLoggedIn === false) {
  return (
    <Nav.Link key={index} as={Link} to={item.link}>
      {item.menuitem}
    </Nav.Link>
  );
}
};
```

Here is what I have in app.jsx:

```
const onGetCurrentUserSuccess = (response) => {
let currentUser = response.item;
if (currentUser.roles === null) {
  currentUser.roles = ["Customer"];
}
```

If the currentUser.isLoggedIn = false, they are directed to NavbarAnonymous

Right now on the app.jax, I have it checking that if the currentuser.roles === nulll then currentuser.roles = ["Customer"]. I just dont think thats the most secure way of handling this problem. My instructor said that " there's a significant issue in that the component cannot handle nulls safely and should be protected from nulls by conditional chaining and other such techniques."

Hopefully the issue is clear and I apologize if it not. I can make any clarifications if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! You can check if their `roles` array has `length` which would indicate it has at least one role. Also, you're already using `conditional chaining` also known as `optional chaining` here:

`item?.roles?.includes`.

This means if `item.roles` is `undefined`, since the `includes()` method then would not exist, to instead return `undefined` instead of error the user's interface.

You could clean things up slightly and account for the situation where a `currentUser` has a `null` or `undefined` `role` by checking for it's length since you know it's an array of strings.

`const userHasRole = roles.length;`

You can also `destructure` the `currentUser` object if you know it's never undefined/null. If `isLoggedIn` or `roles` are undefined/null then you can check for that below.

You could write `mapNavLink.js` like:

```
const mapNavLink = (item, index) => {
  const { isLoggedIn, roles } = currentUser;

  const userHasRole = roles?.length; // <--- protected against undefined / null roles
  const rolesExist = item?.roles?.length; // <--- protected against undefined / null item roles

  if (
    isLoggedIn &&
    userHasRole &&
    rolesExist &&
    item.roles.includes(roles[0])
  ) {
    if (!item.children) {
      return (
        <Nav.Link key={index} as={Link} to={item.link}>
          {item.menuitem}
        </Nav.Link>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <NavDropdownMain
          item={item}
          key={index}
          onClick={(value) => setExpandedMenu(value)}
        />
      );
    }
  } else if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <Nav.Link key={index} as={Link} to={item.link}>
        {item.menuitem}
      </Nav.Link>
    );
  }
};
```

Without seeing more of the `app.jsx`, it's tough to see what's going on. However, you're it's generally best practice to avoid mutating existing objects in React like this:

```
const onGetCurrentUserSuccess = (response) => {
  let currentUser = response.item;

  if (currentUser.roles === null) {
    currentUser.roles = ["Customer"];
  }
  
  //...
  
};
```

Instead, you would want to:

```
const onGetCurrentUserSuccess = (response) => {
  const { item: currentUser } = response;
  
  const updatedCurrentUser = { ...currentUser };
  
  if (updatedCurrentUser.roles === null) {
    updatedCurrentUser.roles = ["Customer"];
  }

  //... other code
};
```